# Using pipeline parameters inside a job

Tags: jenkins

I got this construction in my jenkins:

pipeline -> job -> virtual machine with agent.jar -> batch file

I can successfuly pass parameters from the job to the batch file.
In the job configuration in properties_content I configured like this:

```
JenkinsJobName=foo
JenkinsBuildNumber=${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

Now I want to pass the pipeline name to the job.

I configured in the pipeline script:

```
   environment {
        PIPELINE_NAME    = 'foo-pipeline'
    }
 .. steps { echo "PIPELINE_NAME is ${PIPELINE_NAME}" ... }
```

in the pipeline console I see that parameter has been set:
"PIPELINE_NAME is foo-pipeline"

Now I tried to use this parameter in the job like this:

```
PIPELINENAME=${PIPELINE_NAME}
```

But in the job console I can see that it is taken as a string "${PIPELINE_NAME}" , not as a value.

In my job config these options are activated:

- Keep Jenkins Environment Variables
- Keep Jenkins Build Variables

Comment: I tried to pass a parameter to the job like this:

Pipeline configuration script:
result = build job: jobName, parameters: [string(name: 'myPipelineName', value: "foo-pipeline")]

job config properties_content:
PIPELINENAME=${myPipelineName}

but in job console: / batch file i recieve:
PIPELINENAME=${myPipelineName}

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline configuration script: give a parameter along with the build:

```
result = build job: jobName, parameters: [string(name: 'myPipelineName', value: "foo-pipeline")]
```

job_config:
activate "This project is parameterized" and add parameter "myPipelineName"

job config properties_content:

```
PIPELINENAME=${myPipelineName}
```

now ${myPipelineName} can be resolved
and the batch file recieves the value.